# Elastic Search querying a nested and parent attribute query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have an elastic document as below.

```
{
  "process_id" : "123",
  "user_info" : [{
     "first_name":"A",
     "last_name: "B"
   }]
}

{
  "process_id" : "123",
  "user_info" : [{
     "first_name":"C",
     "last_name: "B"
 }, 
  {"first_name" : "A", 
  "last_name":"D"
  } ]
}
```

**Scenario 1:**

I have not set the nested type to the "user_info" field.
  I search for "process_id" as 123 and first_name as A and last_name as 
  B, I get both the documents in the result.

**Scenario 2:**

The search returns an error. It looks like I will not be able to search for the nested item and the one that is in the parent.

The query is as below:

```
{


 "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "process_id:123",
      "nested": {
        "path": "user_info",
        "query": {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "(user_info.first_name:A AND user_info.last_name:B"
          }
        }
      }
    }   } }
```

The error response is as below.

```
{
"error": {
"root_cause": [
{
"type": "parsing_exception",
"reason": "[query_string] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after [nested]",
"line": 1
}
],
"type": "parsing_exception",
"reason": "[query_string] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after [nested]",
"line": 1,

},
"status": 400
}
```

The ideal response should be when I search for process_id as 123, first_name as A and last_name as B, Only the first document has to be returned.

Note: The attribute names are kept generic in purpose so that the actual can be illustrated.

Comment: Please add the search you're trying to do and the error it throws.

Comment: @KevinQuinzel Updated the query and the error response i received in the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see the following 2 issues in your Scenario 2

- to combine queries you need to use the `bool`-query
- in order to make `nested`-queries work you need to define the "parent"-field as `nested`-field

**1. Declare field `user_info` as of type `nested` in your mappings:**

```
PUT processes
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "process_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "first_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "last_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** the mapping for `user_info` with the extra line `"type": "nested"`

**2. Index the 2 sample documents you provided**

```
POST processes/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"process_id": "123", "user_info": [{"first_name": "A", "last_name": "B"}]}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"process_id": "123", "user_info": [{"first_name": "C", "last_name": "B"},{"first_name": "A", "last_name": "D"}]}
```

**3. Query for a combination of `first_name` and `last_name` using a `nested`-query**

```
GET processes/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "process_id": {
              "value": "123"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "user_info",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "user_info.first_name": "A"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "user_info.last_name": "B"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** the search_request searches for all documents that match the process_id (123) and the combination of `user_info.first_name` and `user_info.last_name` for one particular user (and not across users). In the above setup the query only matches document 1.
If you want Elasticsearch to also tell you which user_info caused the match (in case a process has multiple user_info objects), you can add the following clause to your nested-query: `"inner_hits": {}`.

You may have wondered why I've mapped field `process_id` to a `keyword`-field. This is best practice as `keyword` is the most efficient type to store IDs.

Reference in the Elasticsearch documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html

**Update Oct 13, 2019:** Added version using `queryString`-query

```
GET processes/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "process_id:123"
            }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "user_info",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "user_info.first_name:A AND user_info.last_name:B"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Will try and let you know. I have already defined the parent field as nested. Is it possible to achieve what you have illustrated  using bool query by query_string instead?

Comment: The Elasticsearch `query string`-query is a regular Elasticsearch query and can be used wherever other queries can be used. The `query string`-query accepts Lucene-query syntax in it's query-parameter, which is not as feature rich as Elasticsearch's Query DSL.
I updated the sample code with an example using the `querystring`-query